# Is the Facebook Insights OData feed gone?

Tags: odata, facebook-insights

I'm looking to pull Insights data into excel via oData. The site that everyone is linking to is [here](http://facebook-insights.cloudapp.net) - also referenced by [this URL](http://apps.facebook.com/insightsodata) - but as far as I can tell there's no server at that address.

Is the Facebook Insights oData feed gone?

Comment: You'd have to ask whoever created the data feed - as far as i can tell it's not part of Facebook's product

Comment: Update: yes, this is something Microsoft created, i don't believe it's currently being maintained